# Is 200 reputation not too early for the right of retagging?

Tags: discussion, retagging

Is the privilege of having the right to re-tag other people's questions is being granted here a bit too early? it is currently granted once the user has reached 200 points of reputation, but look, right now my reputation is 201, which means I can do some re-tagging, but I won't dare: I myself don't know how to tag my own questions properly, let alone others'.

Answer (score 5):

Well the simple fact that you don't want to use your right, as you don't think you could use it properly, shows that you are responsible enough not to misuse this right. So no, I don't think it is too early, as reputation is not proportional to the time spent on the Stack Exchange site, but more to the understanding of how a Q&A site works.