# Merge the "retagging" and "retag-request" tags

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request, meta

On meta.english.SE, both the tags are used. [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) is used in three questions, while [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) is used in more questions.
The first should be merged with the second, and made a synonym.

Comment: This question isn't about english.stackexchange, but about meta.english.stackexchange. Therefore you need to ask it on meta.meta.english.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would vote for keeping them separate.

- [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) is a very specific tag for requests of the form "Retag X as Y" or "Get rid of tag Z".
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) is much more broad, for all kinds of questions about retagging.

Look at these two questions:

- [Find question for low-used tag and retag them.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/)
- [Is 200 reputation not too early for the right of retagging?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/)

They are clearly about [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging), but they aren't [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)s.

Comment: Congrats, you’ve won!